# Deep link from toast when tombstoned

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a strange issue in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app. I use toast notifications with deep linking. It works as expected if:

- The app is open
- The app is deactivated but still in memory or
- The app is completely closed.

However, if the app is in a tombstoned state, it doesn't work. The flow I expect to see:

1. Phone receives toast from server, user taps toast
2. Application_Activated event
3. OnNavigatedTo (old page pre-tombstone)
4. OnNavigatedTo (deep link page)

The 4th step doesn't happen. It acts like the user just hit the back button and re-opened the application. I know the push notification is correct because it works in the other scenarios. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a bug in 8.0; sorry. One mitigation is that you could ping your service to see if it had very recently sent a push notification, and then to get the same data again.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help, the user could have multiple toasts with different deep links, so the context of which one they tapped matters. Hmm. That's troublesome. Thanks for the response.